# Change the default Laravel authentificaton email field to user_email

Tags: laravel, custom-authentication, laravel-authentication

Laravel error when I change the `email` field from database to `user_email`

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
>   1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from
>   `ns_users` where `email` = admin@yahoo.com limit 1)

```
Schema::create('ns_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('user_id');
        $table->boolean('active')->default(0);/*by default the user is not active*/
        $table->integer('role')->default(0);/* role 0 means user and role 1 means admin!! */
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('user_email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

Does anybody know what I have to change in default auth to work with `user_email` field instead of `email`?

Comment: you need to override default auth login functionality to work with **user_email** field.

Comment: go through this file `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php` here you can find `username()` function just copy that and paste into  your auth login controller as per laravel version it may b auth controller or login controller. 
`public function username()
    {
        return 'email';
    }` paste this code into it and change return value to `user_email`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, Laravel uses the `email` field for authentication. If you would like to customize this, you may define a `username` method on your `LoginController`:

```php
public function username()
{
    return 'user_email';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getEmailAttribute()
    {
        return $this->user_email;
    }
```

works for me

Comment: you may want to mention that you're doing this in the User.php model

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone of you is manually handling the laravel auth using attempt method.
All you need to do is to change key name 'email' to the one you desired in associative array you are passing to the attempt method.

```
Auth::attempt(['user_email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember)
```